# How to measure how many % is done

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, statistics

Let's say that 100 people are going to two exams. They must pass both.

In the first exam, 20% of people go forward to the next exam. In the 2nd exam, 50% of people complete and therefore complete the whole thing.

In other words, 10% of people complete.

If a person has completed the first exam, how many % of the way has this person gone?

The iterations are $$1/5 \cdot 1/2$$ but I'm not sure how to write this.

In laymen terms:

We start with 100 people. For every 1 person that drops out, you're 1% closer (should be more as you'll only need to reach 90). When 80 people are out, you should logically be 80% closer, right? How would I say this mathematically.

Comment: they've completed 1/2 of the exams. 50%. ;)

Comment: I agree with cygorx. I don't see how one person dropping out effects how close another person is to completing the two exams.